# How to return a string rendered from an html template using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a javascript function like below

```
function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<div class="expandedRow" style="padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 1px; border-color: #f0f0f0;">' + 
  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Full name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.extn + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>'+
    '<div>';
}
```

Clearly it returns a `string`.
But as the html template gets more complicated it is hard to put everything in the return statement.

Is there any way by which I can have the template in some html file as ( `template.html` ) and render the template for the parameter '`d`' and return the resulting string?

I am thinking something like

```
return renderTemplate('template.html', d);
```

Comment: Concatenate in a variable and return that variable...

Comment: Using ES6 template strings could make it easier to write.

Comment: Look in to a templating library, such as [MustacheJS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits your case exactly, however as the application gets bigger it might be better to use the function just to produce data and let something like handlebars take care of the templating aspect. [link](http://handlebarsjs.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery template plugin](https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl) is right for this job.

You put HTML template in a script block (without quotes like your example)

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})
    </li>
</script>
```

and then apply a data set to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var movies = [
        { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
        { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
        { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
    ];
    $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies )
        .appendTo( "#movieList" );
</script>
```